# Error thrown when trying to get DefinitelyTyped's tsd to install angular2 definition

Tags: typescript, package-managers, angular, tsd

I am getting the error below when I run tsd install angular2 from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2015.

I have installed other definitions like "require" successfully so it's not tsd itself or some network issue.

Is it because angular2 is in alpha and I need to configure something for tsd to get it? (Angular.io's 5 min quickstart didn't say anything about this.)

```
PM> tsd install angular2
tsd : stream.js:94
At line:1 char:1
+ tsd install angular2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (stream.js:94:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:559:26)
```

Comment: just tried from the command line with node 0.12.4 / npm 2.10.1 and "tsd install angular2" is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it worked when I just tested it I recommend updating tsd:

```
npm update tsd -g
```

Comment: Thanks. Strange I was getting errors with reinstalling tsd without the specifying @0.6.0, but it worked when I added 0.6.0 then updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command:

npm update tsd